# CalDAV: Where is the URL Component for iOS?

Tags: ios, icalendar, caldav, vcalendar

On iOS, you can create reminders with a URL (https://www.example.com/example.php?key=value) attacted to it (open any web page, open share dialog, tap reminders app).

It syncs correctly between devices (with the full URL), however on my CalDAV server, the To-Do is stored as

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:Open-Xchange
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTAMP:20200622T134803Z
SUMMARY:Example Reminder
DESCRIPTION:www.example.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION
UID:A0F91D70-6F05-4D91-934A-7E7990B873D5
CREATED:20200622T134404Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20200622T134738Z
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

meaning there is no component to store the full URL (the description is only the host and doesn't contain the full request URL).

How can I include the URL so that iOS understands it when creating reminders on the server side?

RFC 5545 has an URL: component that iOS doesn't interpret.

Comment: I'm confused - you already have the url for the file.  If you are 'syncing' - ( I prefer subscribing  because it is usually one way updating, not two way.)  - then the URL you are syncing with is the URL, you don't need to embed it in the file too.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn’t clear. What I mean is that iOS allows for quick actions (try browsing safari and telling siri to remind you of this webpage). This will create a reminder with a “open URL” action. This works on iCloud and CalDAV accounts. However, I can’t figure out where that URL information is stored.

Comment: Ok, I'm not an IOS CalDav developer, was responding from the ICS side.   I was going to suggest maybe the ATTACH property since on my iphone it looks like an attachment, however looks like that is no good either.  A quick google showed this :https://www.oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=AppSuite:CalDAVClients#Reminders which says: 


Unsupported Properties

    The "URL" property for iCal resources is not supported by the OX server and is discarded.
    Importing or exporting file attachments (property "ATTACH") is not supported via the CalDAV interface.

Comment: That’s interesting because as I have stated in my original post, the property does sync between devices. I’ll have a look at ATTACH. Thank you kind stranger!